# Hexagonal architecture and DDD

Tags: kotlin, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture

I have a question reagarding regarding hexagonal architecture and DDD

Is it allowed to call domain logic from persistence adapter which is passed to adapter as an argument?

Example:

```
class DomainService(private val repositoryPort: RepositoryPort,
                    private val domainService2: DomainService2) {
  fun doSomething(id: String?) {
    repositoryPort.doSomething(id) {
      id: String? ->
      domainService2.doSomething2(id)
    }
    println("Doing something")
  }
}

class DomainService2 {
  fun doSomething2(id: String?) {
    println("Doing something$id")
  }
}

interface RepositoryPort {
  fun doSomething(id: String?, consumer: (id: String?) -> Unit)
}

class RepositoryAdapter : RepositoryPort {
  override fun doSomething(id: String?, consumer: (id: String?) -> Unit) {
    println("checking something, searching in database")
    consumer.invoke(id) // Is it allow here to call domain again ?
  }

}
```

Comment: Is it allowed? Sure - there are no DDD/hexagonal police that are going to come for you.  Is code written this way going to give you all of the benefits that you have been promised?   That's a lot less clear.  Do you want to be maintaining code like this, say six months later when you've been working on something else and have forgotten how this was set up?

Answer (score 6):

DDD is a design concept that requires only the following :

- Business code must use object modeling
- That model, and only that, goes in a "domain" component

DDD does not have any constraints on which classes can reference one another or not. In the book, DDD examples use a traditional layered architecture, but the book also states that DDD can be used along with any other software architecture. If you want to use hexagonal architecture it's fine too.

Hexagonal architecture splits application in 3 concentric layers : adapters, ports, business. Hexagonal architecture also states that references are only allowed inwards. This means adapters can reference ports **and** business, ports can reference business, and business cannot reference other layer. In this situation, it is totally licit to reference and call your business layer from your adapter. What would break the pattern is to pass a reference to the port or adapter to the business model.